# Não consigo passar o URL de um arquivo pdf para download sem ser por uma variável estática

Tags: android

Estou utilizando o código abaixo para tentar fazer o download de um arquivo pdf através de uma URL. A activity "**DownloadActivity**" apenas faz o download, sendo que o link URL deve ser passado por parâmetro através de outra activity.

O problema é que o download do arquivo só ocorre quando utilizo uma variável estática para passar o link do arquivo para a classe **DownloadFileFromURL**.

Se eu tentar passar o link utilizando a variável **FILE_PDF**, expressa no código abaixo, o download não acontece.

Existe outra maneira de fazer esse procedimento para o download?  Como posso utilizar uma variável sem ser estática para passar o link?

```
public class DownloadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button mDownload;
TextView mProgressTxt;
ProgressBar mProgress;
String FILE_PDF;
String arquivo;

private static String FILE = "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    arquivo = intent.getStringExtra("nome_arquivo");
    //FILE_PDF = intent.getStringExtra("link_arquivo");

    mDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_baixar);
    mProgressTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_progress);
    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);

    mProgress.setMax(100);
    mProgress.setProgress(0);

    mDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(FILE);
        }
    });
}


private class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressTxt.setText("Baixando arquivo...");
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput(arquivo, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        String plural;

        mProgress.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));

        if (Integer.parseInt(progress[0]) > 1){
            plural = "Transferidos ";
        }else{
            plural = "Transferido ";
        }
        mProgressTxt.setText(plural+progress[0]+"%");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        mProgress.setProgress(0);
        mProgressTxt.setText("O arquivo foi transferido com sucesso!");
    }
}
```

**Como estou passando o parâmetro para a DownloadActivity.class**

```
Intent it = new Intent(getActivity(), DownloadActivity.class);
it.putExtra("nome_arquivo", arquivo);
it.putExtra("link_arquivo", link);
startActivity(it);
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar como está passando o parâmetro **link** e o **arquivo**, por favor? Vai ajudar bastante! Obrigado

Comment: O mais provável é que Extra ("link") que você tenta pegar do intent está nulo.

Comment: Penso em dois erros, um era o parâmetro errado, mas você garante que está vindo certo, o outro é a url estar errada (a url estar com problemas). Quando você pega o valor da outra Activity, ele simplesmente não entra na AsyncTask, ou não abre a conexão??? é meio difícil saber, pois como disse o amigo abaixo, a lógica está certa!

Comment: @MárcioOliveira, realmente você estava certo, o parâmetro estava vazio mesmo. Agora está funcionando. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski, sua linha de raciocínio estava certa também! Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está passando o link no intent com o nome "link_arquivo” e recuperando o Extra usando outro nome ,"link", logo vai ficar nulo. Os nomes tem que ser iguais.

EDIT: O parâmetro passado no intent ("link") pode estar vazio também.

Comment: Já corrigi o enunciado, era só um exemplo, no código está certo.

Comment: Em teoria não tem nada errado com o código então. Já debugou e verificou que no momento do putExtra a variável link está com um valor válido?